# TrackBar: tickbar current (x, y) location on the form

Tags: .net, winforms

Is is possible to get current location of tickbar (Points) in trackback control?

I mean: |----[tickbar]------------------|

EDIT:

Ok. I figured it out. It is just simple math. I had to just test offsets especially left.

```
var value = trackBar1.Value;
var width = trackBar1.Width - 26; //Real width without margins. 26 = right and left offset
var locationX = trackBar1.Location.X + 13; //Real X location. 13 is left offset.
var maxValue = trackBar1.Maximum;
var delta = (double)width / (double)maxValue;

var tickBarLocationX = (int)(locationX + (delta * value));
```

Same thing I can do with Y location.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com) had to go through a lot of pain to figure out all these details when developing their WinForms implementation.  You can get answers to this question, as well as many others, by going through their code.

Your specific question is answered in [ThemeWin32Classic.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ThemeWin32Classic.cs), in the GetTrackBarDrawingInfo() method.